# how to convert list of colors to list of argb values

Tags: c#, image-processing, colors

i want to convert a list of colors into list of ARGB values (int Values) i am using the following c# code:

```
foreach(var element in colorlist)
{
    intlist.add(element.toargb());
}
```

but its taking time is there another faster way?
this how I add colors to the list in the first place:

```
for (int x = 0; x < image.Size.Width; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < image.Size.Height; y++)
            {
                Color c = image.GetPixel(x, y);
                if (histo.ContainsKey(c))
                    histo[c] = histo[c] + 1;
                else
                    histo.Add(c, 1);
            }

        var result1 = histo.OrderByDescending(a => a.Value);
        var Most_Used_Colors = result1.Select(x => x.Key).Take(color_no).ToList();
```

Comment: What language is this? How exactly are your colors stored in the first case (eg. "#rrggbb", "rgb(1,2,3)" or something else). We could be more helpful if we could see more of the code.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to say this code is in c# language 'for (int x = 0; x < image.Size.Width; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < image.Size.Height; y++)
                {
                    Color c = image.GetPixel(x, y);
                    if (histo.ContainsKey(c))
                        histo[c] = histo[c] + 1;
                    else
                        histo.Add(c, 1);
                }'

Comment: Feel free to edit your original question with the extra information, rather than trying to plop code into a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GetPixel method is slow. You can use LockBits method and then iterate the image and get the argb values. Note that this is a lot more complex and requires unmanaged code permissions, but it is also a lot faster. This code should get you on the right track but I do not guarantee you it works completely correctly:

```
        var bitData = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty,image.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        int numBytes = bitData.Stride * image.Height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[numBytes];

        IntPtr ptr = bitData.Scan0;
        // copy the image into an array
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, numBytes);

        for (int i = 3; i < rgbValues.Length; i+= 4)
        {
            var c = Color.FromArgb(rgbValues[i], rgbValues[i - 1], rgbValues[i - 2], rgbValues[i - 3]);
            if (histo.ContainsKey(c))
                histo[c] = histo[c] + 1;
            else
                histo.Add(c, 1);
        }

        image.UnlockBits(bitData);
```